# ImportError: dlopen ... when using tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, devicehive

When I was using a tensorflow model for classification, I got the following error. I am not sure what is the reason. I installed all required packages. I googled for a while but could not find the answer. Can anyone help me with this? (My machine is a Mac.)

The error:

```
/Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
return f(*args, **kwds)
/Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/importlib/_bootstrap.py:219: RuntimeWarning: numpy.dtype size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 96, got 88
return f(*args, **kwds)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "parse_file.py", line 39, in <module>
process_file(**vars(args))
File "parse_file.py", line 29, in process_file
from audio.processor import WavProcessor, format_predictions
File "/Users/user_name/Desktop/project/devicehive-audio-analysis/audio/processor.py", line 18, in <module>
import tensorflow as tf
File "/Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import *
File "/Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 82, in <module>
from tensorflow.python import keras
File "/Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/__init__.py", line 26, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.keras import activations
File "/Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/activations/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.activations import elu
File "/Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras import activations
File "/Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/activations.py", line 24, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.engine import Layer
File "/Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.engine.topology import get_source_inputs
File "/Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/engine/topology.py", line 31, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.utils import conv_utils
File "/Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
from tensorflow.python.keras._impl.keras.utils import data_utils
File "/Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/_impl/keras/utils/data_utils.py", line 23, in <module>
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 26, in <module>
from . import util
File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/util.py", line 17, in <module>
from subprocess import _args_from_interpreter_flags
File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 136, in <module>
import _posixsubprocess
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-darwin.so, 2): Symbol not found: __Py_set_inheritable_async_safe
Referenced from: /Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-darwin.so
Expected in: flat namespace
in /Users/user_name/Desktop/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_posixsubprocess.cpython-36m-darwin.so
```